# Is it a good practice to declare plugins using id("org.company.myplugin") instead of alias(libs.plugins.myplugin) with version catalogs in Gradle?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Gradle version catalogs is a new way to manage dependencies and plugins between different modules in a multi-module project.

Based on the migration to version catalog guide ([Link](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-catalogs)) and the version catalog documentation ([Link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html)), in order to define a plugin in the module-level **build.gradle.kts** file, one should use the syntax below, which will retrieve the plugin's id from the **libs.versions.toml** file.:

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.com.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.hilt)
    ...
}
```

However, looking at the "Now in Android" project ([Link](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/main/app/build.gradle.kts)) which is considered a best practice guide to developing an Android project, we will see that inside each module-level **build.gradle.kts** file, plugins are defined as below:

```
plugins {
    id("nowinandroid.android.application")
    id("nowinandroid.android.hilt")
    ...
}
```

In the nowinandroid app there is no usage of `alais()` thus it is not following the version catalog syntax. All plugins are defined using `id()` which receives a hardcoded plugin id such as "nowinandroid.android.application". This is happening across all of its module-level **build.gradle.kts** files!

#### My Questions:

Firstly, I am wondering, why is that **nowinandroid** project is using `id()` instead of using `alias()` for defining plugins in the **build.gradle.kts** files as per recommendations? For one its not using the version catalog syntax and for other the id is hardcoded across multiple modules which seems to make any possible id change in the future difficult.

Secondly, why (and how) are the ids of the plugins looking customized? For example instead of `id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")` it has used `id("nowinandroid.android.hilt")` which uses their own custom domain for a library such as Hilt!

Comment: Same concern, have you found any answer?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question, at the time of me writing this, outside of a handful of dependencies provided via `id("")` every plugins block seems to be using `alias()` version catalog dependency declaration. And those that I did found to still be using `id("")` like `:core:domain` were probably missed during refactoring.

Another thing worth addressing is the question should nowinandroid be considered best practice. In my opinion, nowinandroid is just an example of how a moderately complex app can be setup for future scalability.
Version catalog is a feature of Gradle, not Android and thus decision what is considered best practice in realm of version dependency management comes from them. Gradle does [recommend](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:version-catalog) to adopt the version catalog. There is also the [idiomatic gradle](https://github.com/jjohannes/idiomatic-gradle) repo by a former Gradle employee and you can see, after [some disscussion](https://github.com/jjohannes/idiomatic-gradle/issues/4) they decided to make version catalog branch the default.

There are several reasons you can still find `id("")` being used and most of these are simply limitations of Gradle model or things that haven't been implemented yet.

For example, it's [impossible](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/15383) to use version catalog ids from precompiled script plugins directly. It's also [impossible](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-use-version-catalog-in-the-root-settings-gradle-kts-file/44603/2) to use version catalog from settings as settings define the version catalog making it a cyclic dependency. Another reason you might see `id("")` being used is due to the way convention plugins are registered:

> Note that identifiers for precompiled script plugins are automatically registered based on the file name of the script plugin.

So, in summary, you should be using version catalogs for listing dependency versions.

As for your second question, the ids look customised since they are actually customised. The plugin defined as `nowinandroid.android.hilt` is defined under the `build-logic` included build alongside other convention plugins.

> Note that convention plugins can be precompiled (written in `.gradle.kts`) or standalone (written in a .kt and registered in `build.gradle.kts`)

Nowinandroid opts in for using standalone plugins but it doesn't mean using precompiled convention plugins is bad. They both server they purposes and use cases. Convention plugins (regardless of their type) allow for extraction of common configuration to centralise that configuration in the single source of truth and allow for easier to read and maintain feature module build files. They also enable developers to get rid of cross configuration via `allprojects/subprojects` allowing them to take advantage of features like [configuration on demand](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_configuration_and_execution.html#sec:configuration_on_demand) and [project isolation](https://gradle.github.io/configuration-cache/).

To summarise,

- there is a convention plugin for a common hilt plugin configuration
- alongside other convention plugins it's bundled into a separate Gradle project called `build-logic`
- this `build-logic` project is treated as an included build by nowinandroid project
- dependencies for these convention plugins are defined in a version catalog
- modules apply the plugins by their alias from a version catalog and utilise the common configuration defined inside

Hope this helps!